# I need to select a range in google sheets script based on a variable range formulated in a a cell

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am converting a macro from VBA in excel to script in google sheets and there's a part where I have specified the ranges to select.

[VBA macro screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7P9n.png)

[image]

The cells being named within the macro are formulated to specify a range that will change based on how many cells have data and are relevant.

[Formula example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4KnQ.png)

[image]

I've figured out the named range element of sheets, but it doesn't help me within the script or when manually recording. I've recorded the rest of the Macro I need but as the ranges vary every time it is used, I need a way of using these variable cells to make sure the correct parts are copied across.

I thought maybe something similar to excels range(range) type of thing might work, but being a self taught VBA user, now. emigrating to sheets is proving a pain in the b...

Hope this makes sense and someone can help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, instead [edit] your question with the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

#### Select a range from a string in the active cell.

```
function getRangeFromActiveCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(sh.getRange('G3').getDisplayValue()).activate(); 
}
```

#### Active Cell Selected

[image: Active Cell Selected]

#### Range in Active Cell Selected

[image: Range in Active Cell Selected]